# How to concatenate variables in Perl

Tags: string, perl, concatenation, string-concatenation

Is there a different way to concatenate variables in Perl?

I accidentally wrote the following line of code:

```
print "$linenumber is: \n" . $linenumber;
```

And that resulted in output like:

```
22 is:
22
```

I was expecting:

```
$linenumber is:
22
```

So then I wondered. It must be interpreting the `$linenumber` in the double quotes as a reference to the variable (how cool!).

What are the caveats to using this method and how does this work?

Comment: Technically you don't need to concatenate the variables, as `print` can take more than one argument. `print '$linenumber is: \n', $linenumber;` works as well. (Although you need to be aware of the built-in variable `$,` (see `man perlvar`).

Comment: `'$linenumber is: \n'` isn't going to do what you want :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Variable interpolation occurs when you use double quotes. So, special characters need to be escaped. In this case, you need to escape the `$`:

```
print "\$linenumber is: \n" . $linenumber;
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
print "\$linenumber is: \n$linenumber";
```

To avoid string interpolation, use single quotes:

```
print '$linenumber is: ' . "\n$linenumber";  # No need to escape `$`
```

Comment: When interpolating variables and the variable name boundary is not clear (e.g. `"my $page = 12; print "$pagep."`), you need to enclose the variable name inside braces `${...}`. I.e. `print "${page}p."`

Answer (score 8):

I like  `.=`  operator method:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text .= "... contents ..."; # Append contents to the end of variable $text.
$text .= $text; # Append variable $text contents to variable $text contents.
print $text; # Prints "... contents ...... contents ..."
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl any string that is built with double quotes will be interpolated, so any variable will be replaced by its value. Like many other languages if you need to print a `$`, you will have to escape it.

```
print "\$linenumber is:\n$linenumber";
```

OR

```
print "\$linenumber is:\n" . $linenumber;
```

OR

```
printf "\$linenumber is:\n%s", $linenumber;
```

[Scalar Interpolation](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Perl_Programming/pickingUpPerl_28.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you change your code from

```
print "$linenumber is: \n" . $linenumber;
```

to

```
print '$linenumber is:' . "\n" . $linenumber;
```

or

```
print '$linenumber is:' . "\n$linenumber";
```

it will print

```
$linenumber is:
22
```

What I find useful when wanting to print a variable name is to use single quotes so that the variables within will not be translated into their value making the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

When formulating this response, I found [this webpage](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/Perl-Concatenating-Text-and-More/) which explains the following information:

```
###################################################
#Note that when you have double quoted strings, you don't always need to concatenate. Observe this sample:

#!/usr/bin/perl

$a='Big ';
$b='Macs';
print 'I like to eat ' . $a . $b;

#This prints out:
#  I like to eat Big Macs

###################################################

#If we had used double quotes, we could have accomplished the same thing like this:

#!/usr/bin/perl

$a='Big ';
$b='Macs';
print "I like to eat $a $b";

#Printing this:
#  I like to eat Big Macs
#without having to use the concatenating operator (.).

###################################################

#Remember that single quotes do not interpret, so had you tried that method with single quotes, like this:


#!/usr/bin/perl

$a='Big ';
$b='Macs';
print 'I like to eat $a $b';
#Your result would have been:
#  I like to eat $a $b
#Which don't taste anywhere near as good.
```

I thought this would be helpful to the community so I'm asking this and answering my own question. Other helpful answers are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can backslash the `$` to print it literally:

```
print "\$linenumber is: \n" . $linenumber;
```

That prints what you were expecting. You can also use single quotes if you don't want Perl to interpolate variable names, but then the `"\n"` will be interpolated literally.

Comment: This is a good point. Something I forgot to mention that. Thought it's not exactly what my question was. +1 anyway.

Comment: the problem with using single quotes (as you suggested) is it will interpret the newline literally, see my edit.