# How should I stringify a variable?

Tags: perl, stringification

When I want to stringify a variable: does it make a difference whether I put the variable in double quotation marks

```
$string = "$v";
```

or whether I concatenate the variable with an empty string

```
$string = '' . $v;
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782435/how-to-concatenate-variables-in-perl possible duplicate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *When I want to stringify a variable*

So never? Operators that expect a string will stringify their operands. It's super rare that one needs to stringify explicitly. I think I've only ever done this once.

> *does it make a difference whether I put the variable in double quotation marks*

The code generated code is different.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'"$v"'
...
3  <#> gvsv[*v] s
4  <@> stringify[t2] vK/1
...
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'"".$v'
...
3  <$> const[PV ""] s
4  <#> gvsv[*v] s
5  <2> concat[t2] vK/2
...
```

This difference will matter for objects with overloaded operators, which is one of the few times you might want to explicitly stringify.

```
$ perl -e'
   use overload
      q{""} => sub { print "stringified\n"; "" },
      "."   => sub { print "concatenated\n"; "" };

   $v = bless({});
   "$v";
   "".$v;
'
stringified
concatenated
```

It will still end up being the same for most classes. You should only have problems with a class for which `.` doesn't mean concatenation.

Comment: 'use Unicode::GCString;
my $v = 42.02;
say Unicode::GCString->new( $v )->columns;
say Unicode::GCString->new( "$v" )->columns;` Here the stringified version returns "5" while the other returns "0".

Comment: It can't handle magical values either e.g. `perl -MUnicode::GCString -E'my $r = \substr("abc",0,1); say Unicode::GCString->new($$r)->columns;'` dies (but `my $r = \"a";` works as expected.)

Comment: Whoa, in the `$v = 42.02;` snippet, `-MUnicode::GCString` instead of `use Unicode::GCString;` works?!