# how to add one value in file output

Tags: perl

My requirement is to read one file and add one value on end of each line. Could any one tell me how I can do that?

Here is my code:

```
open( OFILE, "<$source_path" ) or die "could not open file";

while ( <OFILE> ) {

    my @iline = ( $_ );

    #print "@iline\n";
    #print "$iline[0]\n";
    #print "$iline[1]\n";
    #push @iline, '4';
    #print "@iline \n";

    open( IFILE, ">$target_directory_pacss" );

    {
        foreach ( @iline ) {

            #print IFILE "$_[0]".","."$_[1]".","."$_[2]" ;
            #print  "$_[0]".","."$_[1]".","."$ival" ;
            #print "\n";

            print IFILE "$_";
            print "\n";
        }
    }

    close( IFILE );
}
```

How exactly I want is

#### input

```
patie,1234
patie,1235
patie,1236
```

#### output

```
patie,1234,4
patie,1235,4
patie,1236,4
```

Comment: Well, aside from the slightly weird syntax - we need to know what you mean by 'add one value on each line' - because your code doesn't. So some sample input and expected output would probably help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782435/how-to-concatenate-variables-in-perl

Comment: OK. So - where does that '4' come from? Is it a static value? Or a dynamic one?

Comment: `sed -e 's/$/,4/'`

Answer (score 1):

Below mentioned code is the simplest way to achieve your desired output.
I assume you just need to append something in the end of every line as save it a new file. So as per your required output I have appended ",4" after each line.

This code reads the source file line by line, and writes the new file with the desired modified value.

```
my $source_path = "file.txt";
my $target_directory_pacss = "file2.txt";

open(OFILE, "<$source_path") or die "could not open file";
open(IFILE, ">$target_directory_pacss");

while(<OFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print IFILE $_.",4\n";
}
close( OFILE);
close( IFILE );
```

Using **chomp** : because you need to get rid of the new line character at the end of each line, before appending it with any value.

Output:

```
patie,1234,4
patie,1235,4
patie,1236,4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can work as in the below code. You can firstly read the whole file in an array and then log it to another file with the appended lines.

```
my $source_path = "source.txt";
my $target_directory_pacss = "destination.txt";

open(OFILE,"<$source_path") or die "could not open file";
chomp(my @lines = <OFILE>);
close(OFILE);

open(IFILE,">$target_directory_pacss");

foreach my $line(@lines){
    print IFILE "$line"."EOL"."\n";
}
close(OFILE);
close (IFILE);
```

I have appended the string "EOL" at the end of every line in the above code.

Comment: But really, why would you `foreach` that, when a `while` loop does perfectly well. And also please use 3-arg open with lexical filehandles. It's much better style.

Comment: *"You can firstly read the whole file in an array"* Why would you do that?

Comment: This reading files into array is very useful in case we work with multiple files as the I/O operation take much time and reading the data into memory and then working on it saves lot of time and memory.